# using the facebook app on ipad 2 with a bluetooth keyboard why cant i send messages

Tags: facebook

using a bluetooth keyboard and the facebook app on ipad 2 i cant send a message, along with many, many others who area having the same problem. please patch this problems, or release a new app.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

until they fix this oversight, use your 'show keyboard' button and the on-screen kb AND 'send' button appear. if you don't have a 'show kb' button, try 'Fn + 5' to eject the kb, hence bring up the on-screen kb and send button, then just table a key on the kb again to re-pair it.